# How to use generated protobuf sources correctly?

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers, meson-build

When I try to use sources generated by protobuf '-std=c++11' is added to my compile flags for target that I try to use them in, causing compilation to fail (cause I'm using post C++11 features).
Following a pretty much minimal example.
3 files, all in single directory:

meson.build

```
project('test', 'cpp',
version : '0.1',
default_options : ['warning_level=3', 'cpp_std=c++17', 'werror=true']
)

protoc = find_program('protoc')
proto_dep = dependency('protobuf')

gen = generator(protoc,
  output    : ['@BASENAME@.pb.cc', '@BASENAME@.pb.h'],
  arguments : ['--proto_path=@CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR@', '--cpp_out=@BUILD_DIR@', '@INPUT@'])

generated = gen.process(['defs.proto'])

test_exe = executable(
  'test_exe',
  'main.cpp',
  generated,
  dependencies : proto_dep
)
```

main.cpp

```
#include "defs.pb.h"
#include <chrono>

int main()
{
  using namespace std::chrono_literals;
}
```

defs.proto

```
syntax = "proto2";

package messages;

message Person {
  required string node= 1;
  required string payload= 2;
}
```

After running `meson build && ninja` this fails with following error:

```
[1/3] Compiling C++ object 'test_exe@exe/main.cpp.o'.
FAILED: test_exe@exe/main.cpp.o
c++ -Itest_exe@exe -I. -I.. -I/usr/local/include -fdiagnostics-color=always -pipe -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -Wall -Winvalid-pch -Wnon-virtual-dtor -Wextra -Wpedantic -Werror -std=c++17 -g -pthread -g -std=c++11 -DNDEBUG  -MD -MQ 'test_exe@exe/main.cpp.o' -MF 'test_exe@exe/main.cpp.o.d' -o 'test_exe@exe/main.cpp.o' -c ../main.cpp
../main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
../main.cpp:6:24: error: ‘chrono_literals’ is not a namespace-name
   using namespace std::chrono_literals;
                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../main.cpp:6:39: error: expected namespace-name before ‘;’ token
   using namespace std::chrono_literals;
                                       ^
[2/3] Compiling C++ object 'test...e/meson-generated_defs.pb.cc.o'.
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

The question is: how to fix the meson.build files so that the sources are correctly generated and only `std=` flag passed is specified by `project( default_options`?

Comment: you pass both options `-std=c++11` and `-std=c++17` to the compiler, use only that one that you want to use

Comment: Yes, I understand the reason the compilation fails. Question is how to fix it within `meson.build` file in a clean way.

Comment: ah ok, so the question is actually how to correctly configure meson

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found a dirty solution to the problem, you can get it to compile by passing '-std=c++17' in cpp_args for the target depending on protobuf.

```
proto_interface = declare_dependency(
  sources : generated,
  dependencies : proto_dep
)

test_exe = executable(
  'test_exe',
  'main.cpp',
  dependencies : proto_interface,
  cpp_args : ['-std=c++17']
)
```

This does not seem to be very clean, as there are 3 `-std` flags passed for `test_exe` sources this way, like in the below snippet from `compile_commands.json`:

```
 -std=c++17 -g -pthread -g -std=c++11 -DNDEBUG -std=c++17
```

Answer (score 1):

You can disable all dependency cxxflags with

```
proto_dep = dependency('protobuf').partial_dependency(compile_args : false,
    link_args : true, links : true, includes : true, source : true)
```

If any important flags will be missing you can add them back manually.